# Is it possible to execute anonymous function twice?

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to define a self executing anonymous function, but have it run several times with different parameters.

```
(function(x){ console.log(x*x)})(2)
// output: 4

// I know this syntax is wrong, I am
// demonstrating how I would imagine it being implemented
(function(x){ console.log(x*x)})(2)(5)
// output is error, desired output: 4{Newline}25
```

Is it possible?

---

Edit: Based on answer from @Charmander, it seems it is possible
and almost certainly a bad idea, but this works as I would expect...

```
(function(x){ console.log(x*x); return arguments.callee})(2)(5)
```

Comment: Short answer: no. I will make a longer answer.

Comment: Why does it have to be anonymous? Is it a problem to hold a reference to the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either store the anonymous function in a variable.

```
var someFunction = function(x){
   console.log(x*x);
};

someFunction(5);
someFunction(6);
```

Or you could have the function return itself if you are really bent on making it an immediately-invoked function expression (iife).

```
(function(x){
   console.log(x*x);
   return arguments.callee;
})(5)(6);
```

Comment: And `arguments.callee` is indeed much more compatible than naming a function. +1 (N.B. attempts to access `arguments.callee` will fail in strict mode, but that is not relevant here - just a warning to future viewers, perhaps.)

Comment: is there any alternative to `arguments.callee` in strict mode?

Comment: @BillyMoon An interesting article about arguments.callee to inform future readers further: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you can do it just fine:

```
var f = function(x) {
    console.log(x**x);
    return f;
};

f(5)(6)(7);
```

See here for a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qAgr/

Now, I will grant you, the above is not really an *anonymous* function in the sense that I have sort of given it a name (`f`); so if you literally meant: "Is it possible to do this without having any way of referring back to the function itself?" then I doubt it. Though I could just be lacking in imagination ;)

---

You can actually have even more fun with this (if you're a nerd like me, which you probably are since you're on this site) by defining a function that returns itself while maintaining state at the same time, thanks to JavaScript's ability to add properties to functions:

```
function createCalculator(operation) {
    var result = 0;

    var calculator = function(x) {
        result = operation(x, result);
        return calculator;
    };

    calculator.result = function() {
        return result;
    };

    return calculator;
};

var add = createCalculator(function(x, y) { return x + y; });

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4).result());
```

And here's a demo if you want to see for yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qAgr/1/